# Ajustar Top de WebView debajo de la barra de estado

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo una pequeño código en Android con un WebView que ocupa toda la pantalla. El problema es que la statusBar ( Barra de estado ) se me superpone encima del WebView no dejando que se vea esa parte superior a no ser que haga un scroll hacia abajo con el dedo.

He intentando hacer que el margen en alto del WebView tenga el tamaño en alto del StatusBar pero no me reconoce el código:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/statusBarSize"
```

¿ Hay alguna manera de forzar que el WebView se coloque después de la statusBar ? ¿ Es posible hacer que la statusBar sea transparente ? ¿ Se puede redimensionar el WebView dinámicamente por código sabiendo el alto de la statusBar ?

El código XML del Activity lo tengo de esta manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/visorWeb"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/statusBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Podrias agregar tu código de tu xml de tu activity/fragment que contiene al webview porfa. Me parece que ese webview oculta al status bar, tal vez lo estas forzando a ocultarse con un estilo o por código.

Comment: @rguzman ya escribí el código del XML. Lo que no entiendo tampoco es si esta bien puesto el "match_parent". ¿ No tendría que ser fill_parent ? Como decía el ?attr/statusBarSize como si no estuviera no lo reconoce

Comment: @rguzman revisando el código de nuevo si elimino la línea de Android:layout_marginTop me funciona bien. Parece que el problema viene de la pagina de bienvenida de la URL o del tamaño del WebView. La pagina de bienvenida es responsive se ajusta según el tamaño del navegador para que si este se hace pequeño el logo y bienvenida se centren en la pagina pero parece que aun centrado sobresale el height de la pagina un poco y hay que hacer un scroll. ¿ Es posible entonces sobreponer el statusBar encima del WebView y que el statusBar tenga el background transparente ?

Comment: Genial! Bueno si es posible manejar el background del status bar, cuando indicas sobreponer te refieres a ponerlo en el mismo nivel cierto?

Comment: @rguzman me refiero a poner el webview y encima  el statusBar para que cuando haya una transparencia se vea debajo esa parte del webview que tapa el statusBar. Para eso el Webview tendría que ocupar todo el height de la pantalla y no solo hasta el top del statusBar.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar el efecto, primero tienes que sobrescribir el `theme`de tu app, o si es para una vista en particular, lo podrías agregar como `theme` de tu activity.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Luego, debes agregar un id a tu root layout .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/visorWeb"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/statusBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Luego, en tu clase que contiene este layout agregar los siguientes flags para agregar tu contenido debajo del status bar:

```
rootLayout.setSystemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREE
```

y finalmente si quieres evitar que se oscurezca en el status bar, puedes utilizar windowsInsets

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(visorWeb) { view, insets ->
    visorWeb.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
        topMargin = insets.systemWindowInsetTop
    }
    insets
}
```

Te dejo algunos enlaces de referencia:

- https://proandroiddev.com/draw-under-status-bar-like-a-pro-db38cfff2870
- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/windows-insets-fragment-transitions-9024b239a436
- https://chris.banes.dev/2019/04/12/insets-listeners-to-layouts/

Espero te ayude :)